# How to check curse and how to remove curse

Tags: quran, hadith, curse

The reason i asked this is because i pretty sure i was cursed , after thinking i know what the curse do , and after testing it , it happened .
( I don't know how i was cursed and who cursed me , i literally don't know ) . 
But i'm trying not to be an idiot that have too high imagination and try to find the way to check curse in islam way , but i did not find any such article . 
So i search how to remove curse in islam way at the internet , i find some , i tried , but it does not seemed to be worked because after testing , the curse , still exist .

Al-Qur'an mentioned about curse , but do Al-Qur'an mention anything about checking and removing curse ? If yes , how ?

Comment: How do you know if someone cursed you and how can you even check? Can you explain please?

Comment: Why do you think you are cursed? If something bad happened, it doesn't necessarily mean you are cursed.

Comment: I know i was cursed because everytime i feeling happy , something bad will happen to someone that i know/myself an hour or day later . At first i was thinking it is just accidental thing , so one day i try to feel happy again , then a few hour later , my neighbor fell from floor 2 and had a coma . There are a lot more accident , not just this one . And also , sometimes i had the feeling that i was being watched and my emotion go up and down with no reason ,  just like the answer i marked as 'accepted' below @MarwanAnsari

Comment: @user6668201 Yes the answer below is correct and also make sure you recite Ayatul Kursi multiple times a day specially before going to sleep and in the morning and evening and also when you get scared or feel like someone is watching you. But also remember, when you feel like someone is watching you, remember that Allah is Al-Baseer— The All-Seeing, The All-Perceiving. So if someone is watching you then remember Allah is watching you both. And nothing can harm you if Allah wills and nothing can save you if Allah wills. Seek protection in Allah.

Comment: thanks @MarwanAnsari , and just for additional , i remember now that i was cursed since i was kid , but i just realized it now .

Comment: not quite sure who cursed me , and why .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, 
Hope Allah remove your curse.

First, curse can happen when the devil's (Jin) come to you and give you a curse.

Second, you need to be good Moslem to remove the curse. Not just read one surah and your curse is gone.

To know you has been cursed is, you will feel like someone watching you everywhere you go, or you emotions up and down without any reason. or you feel some illness that doctor do not know what is it.

To remove the curse you need to belive Allah can do anything to help you, go to Mosque for salah 5 times a day ask to him to help you, to cure your curse after salah.

Read surah Al Falaq & An Nass every moring and night before you sleep.

Dont forget wudu' and read Surah Al Iklash, Al Falaq, An Nass before you sleep.

pray to Allah everytime, hope Allah remove your curse.

Comment: Thanks ! , you was right , sometime i feel something is watching me , but i try to ignore *it , and sometime my feeling up and down without any reason .

Comment: Please consider providing evidences to support your claims (see [answer]).